# Clear cache when comment is added

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I am using wordpress total cache, and i need to clear cache every time a comment is added or modified

```
<?php 
 $w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_all();
?>
```

i found this method but , i don't know when to call it ( how to get when a comment is posted/updated )

Answer (score 0):

You would better to contact plugin author, because this is for more general wordpress stuff.

In general, you can clear your cache when comment is added.

There is comment_post hook. This hook will be run when the comment is submitted. To see [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post)

Comment: where can i find the comment_post hook ?
is it in theme's function file ?

Comment: It's wp-core filter. You can use the hook in functions.php in your theme.